# Passing parameters to node when invoked via executable (.bin) npm scripts

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

I've defined an npm CLI command as a `mycommand` module:

```json
{
  ...
  "name": "mycommand",
  "bin": {
    "mycommand": "bin/mycommand.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

where `mycommand.js` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --harmony

console.log('...')
```

I'd like to be able to run it in the following manner, **installed in another module**:

```json
{
  ..
  "scripts": {
    "mycommand": "mycommand --require ./bootstrap"
  }
  ...      
}
```

where `bootstrap` is a module that I expect to be `require`-ed before `mycommand`. The `--require` argument is supposed to be passed to Node running `mycommand`.

**Results & Attempts**

1. **Unfortunately, the `bootstrap` is never required.** There are no errors or other indication of incorrect path resolution or some such.
2. If I define `mycommand` script in a different manner:

   ```json
   {
     ...
     "scripts": {
       "mycommand": "node --require ./bootstrap ./some-random-js-file"
     }
     ...      
   }
   ```

`bootstrap` is required as expected, proving that `bootstrap` exists and `--require` works.

3. If I `require` the `bootstrap` module directly in `mycommand` (which I can't really do -- so just for the sake of the test):

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env node --harmony
   require('../../../bootstrap');
   console.log('...')
   ```

`bootstrap` is required as expected. **Note** that `../../../` is there to compensate for the placement of `mycommand.js` within `node_modules`.

**Assumption**

I assume that `--require` is never actually passed to Node executing `mycommand`.

**Question**

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that `--require` is never passed to `node` is correct:

- When you run `node --require … path/to/mycommand.js` **you are passing arguments to `node`**.
- When you run `mycommand --require …` **you are passing arguments to `mycommand`**.

(And you *could* parse command line options in `mycommand.js` and `require()` as needed, if that fits your use case)

I'm assuming you don't want to use the `node … mycommand.js` method because you need to specify the path to the script, thus loosing the whole point of creating the `bin` field in the first place.

However, since you've provided a `bin` field, you will already have a known path to `mycommand`:

```json
{
  ..
  "scripts": {
      "mycommand": "node --require ./bootstrap ./node_bin/mycommand"
  }
  ...      
}
```

<sup>Or could instead be `… $(npm bin)/mycommand`.</sup>

Comment: Oh, I knew that the args are passed to the command. Assumption was just a way to express that... And running the script via node explicitly is possible, but very ugly. There should be a way of doing it, as some CLI modules allow it. I fear they indeed re-parse and child.exec it....